# What is the difference between executionRoleArn and taskRoleArn and how to find them?

Tags: amazon-web-services

I am new to AWS and I am following this [link](https://aws.amazon.com/getting-started/projects/build-modern-app-fargate-lambda-dynamodb-python/module-two/). I couldn't find the difference between ECS_SERVICE_ROLE_ARN and ECS_TASK_ROLE_ARN. Also I wanted to know how I could find them. I used this command

```
aws sts get-caller-identity
```

But this gives common field "arn". But I don't know which one is this.

Answer (score 5):

The service role Arn is the Arn of the role that is interacting with the ECS service. The task role Arn is the role under which the individual task is executing.

To find the service role Arn, you should be able to look in IAM Roles for the ECS service role.

To find a task role Arn for a given task, you should be able to use: 
`aws ecs describe-tasks`

Answer (score 1):

You could find the ExecutionRoleArn and TaskRoleArn in the json file 'cloudformation-core-output.json', which is generated at the "Step 1 Deploy CloudFormation Templates" after you executed a link:

```
aws cloudformation describe-stacks --stack-name MythicalMysfitsCoreStack > ~/environment/cloudformation-core-output.json
```

Answer (score 0):

**ECS task roles** allow the containers in your task to assume an IAM role to call AWS APIs without having to use AWS Credentials inside the containers.

This means the application inside the container can access other AWS services like sending a notification to Amazon SNS or accessing an S3 bucket or accessing the database for your application.

**ECS task execution roles** grant the ECS agents permission to make AWS API calls which are responsible for managing the tasks in the cluster.

This means the task is able to send container logs to CloudWatch or pull a container image from Amazon ECR.

The execution role can be found in the task definition of your ECS task.